# How to refine the Weibull curve when data are few

Tags: matplotlib, plot, statistics, weibull

I have lists of 5 or 6 members, so when trying to plot my Weibull distribution, I get some polygonal line for Weibull.

For example if this is my data :

[167875, 204128, 205356, 268522, 413577, 669845]

my plot will be like :

[image: Weibull plot]

apart from the fact that my vertical values are so small (are they ok ?) , I also want to make the Weibull curve look finer, some thing like :

[image: Weibulexample]

I put my code here as well, I repeat : What I am searching for is to refine the curve and not the bins so my polyline curve will look more curved like the dotted one in the second graph

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots();
fig = plt.figure()
plt.show()
plt.plot(data, s.exponweib.pdf(data, *s.exponweib.fit(data, 1, 1, scale=2, loc=0)))
fig.show()
plt.hist(data, bins = np.linspace(data[0], data[-1], 30), normed=True, alpha= 1);
plt.ion()
plt.interactive(True)
plt.rcParams['interactive'] == True
plt.show()
```

Update 1 : Trying the suggestions in the answer by user @ImportanceOfBeingErnest :

If I set the bins thickness to 3 as suggested I will have :

[image]

and if I set it to 100 I  have :

[image]

so I tried with a and c (shape and scale) , but still wasn't so successfull to change significantly, (but now the curve is much better).

Comment: You may evaluate the pdf with a finer gridding, instead of the original `data`, use e.g. `np.linspace(data[0], data[-1], 100)`. For the binning, you may in contrast coarsen the gridding, e.g.  `bins = np.linspace(data[0], data[-1], 6)`.

Comment: thank you but no this is not what I was searching for, it only deals with bins, not with the curve shape

Comment: You have two issues. I gave a solution to both.

Comment: dear Ernest, well , by my first issue, I meant the numrical value on the vertical axis. I am just not sure if I am using the function correctly,  but for the second one, I prefer to change the curve's fineness rather than touching the bins

Comment: Ok, so ignore the second sentence in the first comment. The first sentence remains valid and solves the problem of "the curve's fineness".

Comment: Dear Ernest, shall I ask you : do you confirm that there's no way to get a curve like the second one having only 5  points?

Comment: Any trick is welcome

Comment: The first sentence of the first comment *is* the "trick". Did you try it? If so and if it then did not work, you may of course update your question with the code where you try that concept.

Comment: Dear Ernest, I updated my post

Comment: When @ImportanceOfBeingErnest is suggestiing is something like this:  replace `plt.plot(data, s.exponweib.pdf(data, *s.exponweib.fit(data, 1, 1, scale=2, loc=0)))` with `x = np.linspace(np.min(data), np.max(data), 100); plt.plot(x, s.exponweib.pdf(x, *s.exponweib.fit(data, 1, 1, scale=2, loc=0)))`

Comment: Thank you so much ! I corrected it, now it's more close to a curve, but Its peak is not similar, do you have a suggestion for this part ?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Could you please make it an answer ?

Comment: My comment was just a possible implementation of ImportanceOfBeingErnest's suggestion.  If the suggestions in the comments have provided enough hints for you to solve the problem, you should answer the question yourself!  That's allowed and even encouraged on stackoverflow.